# Responsive Div class rows across another div

Tags: html, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone help me? I have a problem when DIV with class `rows` gets above another div `rows`.

In Desktop View
[image]

Output expected Mobile View
[image]

Comment: So what have you tried? What is your current HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some custom styles:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}

.row{  /* for visual purpose */
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.container>div:first-of-type{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index:10;
}

.container>div:nth-of-type(4){
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom : 10px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index:10;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){ /* reset the custom styles on mobile */
    .container>div:first-of-type, .container>div:nth-of-type(4){
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/vsGAZgGPbA)

Comment: Thanks...I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bootstrap here.

On desktop layout apply css

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}

.first-div {
     position: absolute;
     left: 30px;
     top: -10px;
     width: 150px;
     height: 250px;
}

.fourth-div {
     position: absolute;
     right: 10px;
     top: 10px;
     width: 150px;
     height: 600px;
}
```

And on mobile view apply

```
.first-div {
     position: static;
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
}

.fourth-div {
     position: static;
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
}
```

with html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="first-div"></div>
    <div class="second-div"></div>
    <div class="third-div"></div>
    <div class="fourth-div"></div>
</div>
```